# Video is not playing using mediaplayer and surfaceview

Tags: android-mediaplayer

```
public  class PlayVideoActivity extends Activity implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
SurfaceView surfaceView;
SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_play_video);
        Intent intent=getIntent();
        int no=intent.getIntExtra("index",0);
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Hello",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        getWindow().setFormat(PixelFormat.UNKNOWN);
        surfaceView = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surfaceView1);
        surfaceHolder = surfaceView.getHolder();
        surfaceHolder.addCallback(this);
        surfaceHolder.setFixedSize(176, 144);
        surfaceHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        mediaPlayer.setDisplay(surfaceHolder);

        try {
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(MainActivity.musicPath[no]);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            mediaPlayer.prepare();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        mediaPlayer.start();
    }
```

I'm trying to play video using mediaplayer and surface view, but it is not playing,i writing my code here .please tell me the what is the problem in my code? thanks in advance
.......................................................................................................................................................................................

Comment: Do you observe any errors? When you say not playing, what was the expectation and what was the observed result?

Comment: Looking at your code, I have a doubt. Are you passing a video file to `MediaPlayer`? From your sources above `mediaPlayer.setDataSource(MainActivity.musicPath[no]);` indicates that you are passing a music file. Hence, even if you set a surface, it will not display anything because the `MediaPlayer` will become a simple `MP3` player. Can you confirm that after passing a video file in `setDataSource` method call, you are still able to observe the issue?

Comment: can't we play video using mediaplayer?I heard that using mediaplayer we can play audio as well as video,if i'm wrong please correct me.and mediaPlayer.setDataSource(MainActivity.musicPath[no]); here i'm passing path of video.Before i played video using videoview and mediacontroller,it is working fine,But when i tried to play video using mediaplayer and surfaceview it is not playing,and showing FATAL EXCEPTIONS like that.please tell me what is wrong in my code..... thanks in advance

Comment: @user2155454... Yes you are right. `MediaPlayer` can be used to play audio and video. I was just checking if you were indeed passing a video file. Can you share your logs where you observe errors? This will be helpful to analyze your issue and help you localize the same.

Comment: hi ganesh i'm sharing my log files here

Comment: @user2155454... I couldn't find the link to log files. Can you please check?